# How do servers and clients communicate properly?

Tags: networking

Let's take a first person shooter game as an example, the server would have to track the players position, actions, health, etc. How does the client send the server this information? And how can the server differentiate whether the client is sending it a players positions or a players new health?

Comment: In short, magic.  In long, it's got a lot of data.  [Here's minecraft's protocol system, as an example](http://wiki.vg/Protocol).

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on my own game, its a online multiplayer farming game but conceptually the server will handle it in a similar way.

The first question is on the implementation. For example, I use Socket Channels to differentiate various players. When a player moves for example, I'll have a packet send from the client to the server indicating the movement (in this case, the new coordinates). That information is sent over the channel for that player and updates that players information.

For handling a multitude of types of data, you would need some sort of identifier to septate various types of information... for example, switch/if statements. This is not very useful, but here is some sudo code below just for an example.

```
if (packetCode == "Players-Health-Change") {
  player.setHealth(newHealth);
} else if (packetCode == "Players-Location-Change") {
  player.setLocation(newLocation);
}
```

It is very specific however to what you want to run the system on, and the architecture. I'd recommend grabbing a book/tutorial on the subject.

**Useful Links:**
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/

Comment: Problem a) comparing strings with `==` instead of `equals` b) It's very unlikely that a FPS(or any other game that needs to transfer much data) uses Strings to represent the data type; It's just to much data to waste bandwidth on data that can be represented in a more compact way (using a integral data type to represent the data) and CPU time (selecting the right case based on a string is less efficient than selecting the right case, if the data is represented as number).        But of course the general idea is correct (i.e. Send data that identifies the information type along with the data).